# Complex numbers simplify

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm new here and I'm studying complex numbers is there a way the simplify this:

$$\left(\frac{45\sqrt{3}i}{i^\pi}\right)^{\pi \times 5}$$

Comment: A naive calculation gives $(45\sqrt3)^{5\pi}i^{(1-\pi)5\pi}$, but things depend on how you define noninteger powers of complex numbers. It depends on the choice of the branch for the logarithm if you define $a^b:=e^{b\log(a)}$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{45\sqrt{3}i}{i^\pi}\right)^{\pi \times 5}=\left(\frac{45\sqrt{3}i}{i^\pi}\right)^{5\pi}=$$

$$\left(\frac{\left|45\sqrt{3}i\right|e^{\arg\left(45\sqrt{3}i\right)i}}{\left|i^\pi\right|e^{\arg\left(i^\pi\right)i}}\right)^{5\pi}=$$

$$\left(\frac{45\sqrt{3}e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi i}}{1e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}(\pi-4)\pi\right)i}}\right)^{5\pi}=$$

$$\left(\frac{45\sqrt{3}e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi i}}{e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}(\pi-4)\pi\right)i}}\right)^{5\pi}=$$

$$\left(45\sqrt{3}e^{\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}(\pi-4)\pi\right)\right)i}\right)^{5\pi}=$$

$$\left(45\sqrt{3}e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\pi-5)\pi\right)i}\right)^{5\pi}=$$

$$\left(45\sqrt{3}\right)^{5\pi}e^{5\pi\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\pi-5)\pi\right)i}=$$

$$\left(45\sqrt{3}\right)^{5\pi}e^{\frac{5}{2}\pi^2(\pi-5)(-1)i}$$

Comment: Wow, I've checked it in Wolfram and it true! Thanks a lot